# Updated iOS Applications Agreement

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am trying to upload my app but I get this error when I try to upload it through Application Loader:

> A new version of the iOS Paid Applications Agreement with updated pricing information is now available in the Contracts, Tax, and Banking module.
>
> To be able to continue creating new apps and upload binaries for the App Store, your Team Agent must review and agree to the updated terms of the iOS Paid Applications Agreement. To access the iOS Paid Applications Agreement, you must have accepted the latest version of the iOS Developer Program Agreement in the iOS Dev Center on developer.apple.com.

It's clear that they want me to accept the new agreement but I can't find it anywhere.

Could anyone explain where I can get it?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, it's easiest to find via [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com), so go there and log in. Select 'Contracts, Tax, and Banking'. You should see a contract with a 'request' button next to it. Request that contract.

Comment: Thanks. Why on earth don't they use the same language on the instructions as in the module? Telling me to "review" and "agree to" an agreement doesn't give me much of a clue that what I in fact have to do is "request" an "amendment"...

Comment: @MattGibson hehehe exactly, it's good there's this stackoverflow question... And look how many upvotes there is

Comment: Works as a solution for the following error code on : Xcode 6.1. - Organizer - Validate - popup message:"failed to find apps with content hosting on itunes connect".

Comment: For now we have to click `Agreement, Tax and Banking` and in the Paid Apps there will be "View" button from where you can read and agree to got further.

Comment: [] I have read and agreed to the terms presented above.

Check box only show "Account Holder" user! :)
(Users and Access)