# IAP creation - No "Hosted Content"

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, iap-hosted-content

I'm looking to update one of my older apps in the next week or so and want to implement hosted in app purchases rather than my old server strategy.

According to the docs I'm reading it says this "In the Hosting Content with Apple section of the In-App Purchase Details page, click Yes"; however I can't see that box when I create any new in app purchases. Is there some reason that option is not showing up for me?

Comment: So basically do you want to set hosting content with apple to "Yes"??? and do you want to set "Yes" for new in app purchase you are going to create?

Comment: That is correct @manthan

Comment: If you are going to create nonconsumable in app purchase then you can set this option to "Yes" and even you can edit in the edit section of the InAppPurchase details section.

Comment: @ManthanPatel yes this is what I have read everywhere... but when I click on the 'Non-Consumable' option when creating an in app purchase, setting this to 'Yes' isn't even appearing on the website

Comment: When i try to create new non consumable in app purchase there is an option for me "hosting content with apple" and I can set that to "Yes". I don't understand where your problem lies.

Comment: Me neither... I've sent a note to apple support as well. Definitely frustrating

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did anyone find a way to solve this?

Comment: Mine turned out to be the paid app contracts in itunes connect. It was not intuitive that I hadn't accepted, just check your 'expiration dates' in that section.

Comment: Hello, I checked and there's almost two months before the contracts expire. Do you know of anything else that may cause this? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it turned out that there was an amendment that needed to be accepted. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad it was helpful... it can be really frustrating :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your paid app contracts ;)

Answer (score 1):

Having a look myself, I can't see the option to turn it on either. But I thought it was worth mentioning as you're updating old apps, this feature is only available on iOS 6 onwards. Just so you're aware!

Comment: Thanks for the note. Yes I am aware it's only available ios6+ (I'm ok with requiring that).. but even with newly created apps I can't seem to find that option to turn on

Comment: So it turns out this was because I had expired contracts in itunes connect. If you want to edit your answer to include information about checking your paid app contracts I'll award you the answer + bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to "review" my "iOS Paid Applications Agreement". This means going to iTunes connect - then "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" click the "Request" button and accept all the changes...

After this every problem was gone. Got the answer from this stackoverflow site:

[Updated iOS Applications Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462398/updated-ios-applications-agreement)

Works also for the following error code on : Xcode 6.1. - Organizer - Validate - popup message:"failed to find apps with content hosting on itunes connect"