# can't get In-App-Purchase hosted content to be actually hosted

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase, iap-hosted-content

I have an iPad app with In-App Purchase that used to host its content with Urban Airship (a pox upon their house).  Now I'm trying to convert this to use Apple's hosted content.

I've created a .pkg file for one of my content items, and used Application Loader (multiple times now) to upload the content.   The package passed validation, I clicked "Deliver," and I watched the progress bar as it was "Uploading package to the iTunes Store."  In the "Hosted Content" tab for this item, "Host Content with Apple" is clearly checked, and the "Hosted Content Package:" well shows the standard package icon.

Yet, when I look at the same app on iTunes Connect, and go to In-App Purchases and view the same content item, it says: "Hosting Content with Apple: This feature is turned off."  (And no hints are provided here as to how one might turn it on.)

In my code, when I get back the SKProduct from StoreKit, I find that downloadContentVersion and downloadContentLengths are both nil.  And when I purchase it anyway using a test account, I get a SKPaymentTransaction whose .downloads is also nil.  And if I quit and relaunch Application Loader, the "Host content with Apple" checkbox is now unchecked.  This is all probably related to the fact that Apple doesn't realize they are now hosting this content.

Perhaps life is more difficult because this is not a new app or new content item; both of these were approved long ago, and I'm trying to update them to the new model.  But I certainly don't want to create a new app just for this.  What's the key step I'm missing that makes the Apple servers actually host this content?

Answer (score 0):

I had to "review" my "iOS Paid Applications Agreement". This means going to iTunes connect - then "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" click the "Request" button and accept all the changes...

After this every problem was gone. Got the answer from this stackoverflow site:

[Updated iOS Applications Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462398/updated-ios-applications-agreement)

My problem wasn't similar to yours but I have read similar so posts with the same solution that did it for me. Try it out. Hope it helps you or anyone else :)

Comment: I completed this step and filled out all of the paperwork, however the IAP page still says "This features is turned off.".