# Hosting content with apple - This feature is turned off

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an iOS app with in-app purchases which I host their contents on Apple's server. I was able to do that previously, now when I try to add a new in-app purchase, the hosted content with Apple feature is turned off. I checked this answer [can't get In-App-Purchase hosted content to be actually hosted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435349/cant-get-in-app-purchase-hosted-content-to-be-actually-hosted) and this one [Updated iOS Applications Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462398/updated-ios-applications-agreement) which state that Apple might have updated its policy and I need to update my contracts, but I can't find request button next to my paid contracts. Has anyone faced the same problem before? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit weird. When you first create the in-app purchase in iTunes Connect it does not allow to select hosting content with Apple. Solution: don't bother, just store what you have entered. Then select edit again and, voilà, you now are allowed to select hosting content with Apple.